# Is it possible to take input port as array in verilog?

Tags: verilog

```
 module median_five(out1,a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],en,clka);             
    input [7:0] a[0:4];              
    output out1;              
    endmodule
```

**It is giving error.

```
 module median_five(out1,a,b,c,d,e,en,clka);             
        input [7:0] a,b,c,d,e;              
        output out1;              
        endmodule
```

**It is right.

But I want input a,b,c,d,e in array like :

```
array[0]<=a;            
array[1]<=b;               
array[2]<=c;             
array[3]<=d;            
array[4]<=e;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Verilog **does not support two dimensional arrays** as ports of modules. This feature is supported by **SystemVerilog** only.

In the **first** snippet, you are passing **two dimensional array** `a` as input, which is not supported. In the **latter** case, a **single dimensional vector** is passed to the module which works fine.

It is *not clear* what you want to do with `array`. Here are some **options**. You can **declare two dimensional array inside the module** itself. Something like follows:

```
module median_five(out1,a,b,c,d,e,en,clka);
input [7:0] a,b,c,d,e;
output out1;

ref [7:0] array [5]; // array local to module

//always @(posedge clka)  // use non blocking assignments
always @(*)              // use blocking assignments
begin
// .. Some stuff
array[0]=a;            
array[1]=b;               
array[2]=c;             
array[3]=d;            
array[4]=e;     
//..       
end

//.. some other stuff

endmodule
```

Another thing you can do is to **flatten the array** and pass it as inputs. Here, I have flattened **each of 8 bit input** (`a`,`b`,`c` etc. each) into a **single vector** (`in`) and assigned each **individual element of array** accordingly.

```
module top (in, out);
  input   [31:0] in; // flattened array as input
  output  [31:0] out;

  wire     [7:0] array [0:3]; // local array

  assign {array[3],array[2],array[1],array[0]} = in;
  //... some operations/procedural blocks etc.
  assign out = {array[3],array[2],array[1],array[0]};
endmodule
```

Refer to [Inputs as two dimensional array](http://dbaspot.com/arch/254210-inputs-array-verilog.html) link for a similar question. There is a [similar blog post](http://chandujjwal.blogspot.in/2011/06/declaring-2d-array-io-ports-in-verilog.html) too.

Comment: I wanted to do the sorting. That's y I needed elements in an array . Thanks

Comment: reg [3:0] r=1; r<= r+ ((e>a) + (e>b)+ (e>c) +(e>d)); its giving unknown value in output. But when i wrote reg [3:0] r=1; r<= ((e>a) + (e>b)+ (e>c) +(e>d)); Its giving output accordingly but i wanted to the first expression r<= r+ ((e>a) + (e>b)+ (e>c) +(e>d)); needed to simulate correctly. Please give hint.

Comment: Using the first equation, you might be creating a [combinational loop](http://fpga-hdl.blogspot.in/2012/07/test.html) and thence output might not be as per requirement. One method of avoidance of combinational loop is described [here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/121161/understanding-combinational-feedback-loops). I have created a sample at [EDAPlayground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/eke).